# Import data into Expression Engine channels content

Tags: import

How can I import data into Expression Engine channels?
There is a way to do it with the core functionality or there is a plugin for that?
I need to import special characters too (ex: á é í)

Answer (score 2):

You can use datagrab fot that http://brandnewbox.co.uk/news/details/datagrab-for-expressionengine-3